# Pin items from navigation to a separate sidebar (bookmarks)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating something many would call a bookmark bar, but within the website itself. Basically I have a regular Bootstrap `navbar` with few menu items that have a "thumb-tack" on them. By pressing the thumb-tack, user can pin that menu item for quick access to a sidebar I've created.

Now before this explanation goes way too messy, here is my current code, which is partially working, but on the other hand it is not.

> [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ProDexorite/08qd382z/)

**HTML**

```
<nav id="oa-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li class="active">
                     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-area-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Dashboard</a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit content</a>
                 </li>

                 <!-- PINNABLE MENU ITEM!! -->
                 <li class="pinnable">
                     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Media</a>
                 </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
</nav>


<!-- The "Quick-Access" navbar -->
<div id="oa-toolbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div id="oa-toolbarbtn" class="oa-btn btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Quick-Access
                </div>
                <div id="oa-toolbar-pinned">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
// Adding the "pinicon" to the pinnable link
$.each($("#oa-navbar li"), function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("pinnable")) {
        var pinicon = '<a class="pin-it"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
        $(this).find("a").append(pinicon);
    }
});

// Pinning the link itself
$("#oa-navbar li .pin-it").click(function () {
    var pinMenu = $("#oa-toolbar-pinned");
    var nl_content = $(this).parent().html();
    var nl = $("<li class='pinnedItem'>"+ nl_content +"</li>");

    $(pinMenu).removeClass("active");
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("pinned")){
        $(nl).appendTo(pinMenu);
        $(pinMenu).addClass("active");
    }
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("pinned");

});
```

The way it works now is that it does add the menu item to the quick-access menu, but it does not take the `<a>` tags, just what's inside of them.

The other issue is that when I press the thumb-tack on the navigation bar again, it does not remove the pinned item from the quick-access menu. There's got to be an easy way to do this, but I've taken the long road it seems.

Any advice will be more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/08qd382z/14/), actually you were close, I have just reversed your code

```
$("#oa-toolbar-pinned").on('click','.pinnedItem',function () {
    var navBar = $("#oa-navbar ul li"); // find navbar
    var content = $(this).find("a").html(); 
    var appendCont = "<li class='pinnable'> <a class='pin-it' href='#'>"  + content  + "</a></li>"; // take content and surround with li
    $(appendCont).appendTo(navBar.parent()); // append to navbar
    $(this).remove(); // remove from pinned list

});
```

### Edit 1:

Changed click event to `delegate`, because there was a problem that newly appended `a` tags don't fire click event, solved with this,

```
$(document).on('click', '#oa-navbar li .pin-it' ,function() {}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Thanks for your response! Otherwise it seems to be working just fine, but for some reason it also appends the link to the very end of my `#oa-navbar` after it is "unpinned" from the `#oa-toolbar-pinned`, which causes the link to double after each unpin. Also, I do not want the links to get removed from the `#oa-navbar` - does it require rocket science to change it or can you provide a tip/solution for that? :)

Comment: If you don't want to remove delete this  `$(this).remove();`, and Just checked it add to `#oa-toolbar-pinned`, you can check with developer console. Btw this an working example that shows how to use jquery functions to solve your problem. You can easily change over it now :) @ProDexorite

Comment: When I comment out the `$(this).remove();` I get back to the starting point, where when I press the "pin" three times on the navbar, I get the link as double in the toolbar. Any way to prevent this from happening? Like checking if the link already exists in the toolbar before adding it?

Comment: I have made just for "pinning items" here is the jsfiddle [result](https://jsfiddle.net/08qd382z/17/), you can convert it to unpin :) @ProDexorite

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for - in that fiddle you can pretty much spam both of the menu's full of links. I asked for a way to prevent any sort of scenario where there could be duplicates of the same link. Could you help me with that? :) So as a baseline: User can pin the menu-item from the navbar to the toolbar - if it does not exist in the toolbar already. The pinned link should not be removed from the navbar, but the "pin-icon" should of course be removed once the certain link has been already pinned.

Comment: In that fiddle; from navbar to toolbar, I have prevented duplication. Are you sure that you are looking at right link ? https://jsfiddle.net/08qd382z/17/

Comment: Ah, now I see! It confused me when I was able to duplicate the link back to the navbar and from there, add multiple duplicates to the toolbar. Great, thank you very much, I think I can get on with this now! :)